# Fatal error: Call to undefined function lock_initialize()

Tags: 7

I am getting this error on a Drupal 7 site on Ubuntu 12.10.  I downgraded PHP from 5.4 to 5.3, but am still getting it.

Does anyone recognize this error?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function lock_initialize() in /home/buck/drupal/cms/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 2366

Comment: Make sure there's a file called `includes/lock.inc` in your Drupal installation, that it's the correct (un-hacked) version of the file, and that your web server can read it :)

Comment: Yes, got it.
-rwxrwxr-x 1 buck buck 0 Aug 29 09:46 lock.inc

Comment: It is running as www-data, and I just added buck to that group, and restarted the server, and still got the error.

sudo usermod -a -G www-data buck

Comment: The file permissions would make it readable to world anyway so that wasn't it, I removed that comment. There are [some rumblings](http://drupal.org/node/1305178) that it might be APC related, are you able to disable APC temporarily to test that?

Comment: I don't think I am using it.  I don't see any references to it under /etc/php5

Comment: Hmm that's strange, no other opcode cache enabled I suppose? Other than that it's just a matter of logic...the lines where you're getting the error are `require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('lock_inc', 'includes/lock.inc'); lock_initialize();`...so the file has been successfully included (otherwise a different exception would have been thrown). But PHP is complaining that `lock_initialize()` doesn't exist...so it stands to reason that function isn't declared in the `includes/lock.inc` file. If it is, I'd wager you've got a rogue opcode cache doing something nefarious.

Comment: Are you by chance using a memcache module?  If so, check the file permissions on memcache/memcache-lock-code.inc ... that module has a lock_initialize() function which can server as a failover.

Comment: Just looking at that `ls` output, it's clear that the file size is `0` => `-rwxrwxr-x 1 buck buck 0 Aug 29 09:46 lock.inc`. Can you check to see if the file is empty? If it is, then you just need to reupload it or pull from repo or w/e. This often happens when you use FTP and if the connection was interrupted.

Comment: You may want to check all the other file integrity as well. The only way to quickly make sure is to unpack a fresh drupal on top of it (essentially performing a core update). If you do this (upgrade), don't forget to run database updates.

Comment: I gotta stop posting comments to 3 year old questions.

Comment: This just happened to me because I ran out of disk quota while trying to upgrade with `drush pm-upgrade`. Old questions are useful!

Answer (score 1):

The function is called using code similar to the following, from Drupal.

```
  // Initialize the lock system.
  require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('lock_inc', 'includes/lock.inc');
  lock_initialize();
```

[_drupal_bootstrap_variables()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_variables/7) is the only Drupal function that calls `lock_initialize()`.

That code could fail if the file whose name is contained in lock_inc doesn't exist, but in that case I would expect another warning/error message, or it doesn't contain a function called `lock_initialize()`.

I would check if there is code that sets `$conf['lock_inc']`, and which value is used. I would also check if there is code calling `variable_set('lock_inc', ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. It occurred when I mysqldump'd my drupal db from my local dev machine and dumped it into my production db. I believe one of the cache tables had an entry that was referencing a file path that doesn't exist on my production server.

My fix: truncate all cache tables

I also restarted apache after that, but restarting apache was likely unnecessary. If you're running on linux, here's an easy command to truncate all your cache tables:

```
echo "show tables" | mysql yourdb | fgrep cache | xargs -I {} echo "truncate {};" | mysql yourdb
```